# Determine the most likely

Tags: probability

The germination of cactus seeds is not easy. From experience, Lyla, an expert cactus grower, knows that on average, only 40% germinate. An intrepid collector returns from a very dry desert with six seeds of a previously unknown type of cactus.

Determine the most likely number of seeds to germinate (highest probability)

I know I can find the probability of each and then see which is highest. Is there a different way?

Comment: The expected value of the number of seeds to germinate is $p n = 0.4*6 = 2.4$

Comment: @JohnMcGee I know the expected value. I want to know what is the most probable number of seeds that will germinate. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6

Comment: The mode of a binomial distribution is always very close to the mean. In your case $P(k=2)=0.31104$ is the most probable.

Comment: @JohnMcGee how did you calculate that? How did you know that k=2 is most probable?

Comment: The mode of a binomial distribution usually the largest integer smaller than $(n+1) p$.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Mode_and_median

Comment: @JohnMcGee Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the binomial distribution, (easy to find online) the probability that $k$ seeds generate is ${6 \choose k}(0.4)^k(1-0.4)^{6-k}$. The maximum will always occur either left or right of the expected value of the distribution, which is $6 \cdot 0.4 = 2.4$. So you just need to compute the binomial distribution probability values for $k=2$ and $k=3$ to find the maximum.